# Android - scrolling bitmap in custom view

Tags: android, bitmap, scroll

I have a bitmap with the size of 400 x 70 pixels. I would like to scroll this bitmap up by one row and fill up row 70 with new pixels. 
I have tried to scroll the bitmap by copying it to an IntBuffer , copy it to another IntBuffer (starting at the second row) and the then write it back to the bitmap.
This works but it takes a lot of CPU power and it is kind of slow. 
Is there any faster way to do this?

```
private Bitmap shift(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    buffer.rewind();
    buffer1.rewind();
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    buffer.position(bitmap.getWidth());
    buffer1.put(buffer.array(), bitmap.getWidth()*2, bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight());
    buffer1.rewind();
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer1);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it using canvas:

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, bgrPosition, 0, null); 
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0 - bgrW + bgrPosition, 0, null);

    //next value for the background's position 
    if ( (bgrPosition += bgrDx) > bgrW){
        bgrPosition = 0;
    }
```

bgrDx is the speed of scrolling try bgrDx = 1, while bgrW is the width of the bgr bitmap.
This method repeats the image and produces an infinite scroll, however you would need to use a looped image (the same on both ends) to make the scroll look seamless. Perhaps you should experiment with this and see if it performs any better for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You gave me a good hint. I am using now a second canvas with an underlaying bitmap and I scroll it with: canvas1.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, -2, null);  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0, 0, p);

Comment: if you scroll a smaller area on a canvas which belongs to a view then you can use canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, fromRect, toRect, null); where fromRect = new Rect(0,0,bitmap.getWidht(),bitmap.getHeight()) and toRect = new Rect(x,y, x + w, y + h); i.e. a rectangle on canvas. In this way you can avoid using new canvas1